# How can i read my Json String from Delphi in Java

Tags: java, json, delphi, class, rest

my Json Strin is

```
{"result":[[{"Name":"Mos","Family":"Hos"},{"Name":"Mos","Family":"Hos"}]]}
```

i connect to rest server and get this string in java but i cant pars this string to a class in java with gson .
what class i need in Java for read this string.

Comment: Try using [Json in Java](http://json.org/java/)

Comment: You can't just parse it to any class. You need to have the class that represents this json structure. If not, you need to traverse through the arrays in the json manually. Gson does let you do that. Did you try that?!

Comment: R.J  how can i try this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSon is a format that doesn't depend on the language. You can create it in Delphi/C/even code by yourself and read in any other language.
In Java its easy because there are a lot of thirdparties that handle this.
To name a few:

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

[JSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

[JavaJSon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javajson/)

[FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)

I'm sure there are others. I think the most widespread are gson and jackson

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use jackson api for this. may this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) will help to achieve this.

Comment: i see this but i cant defined true class like this
public class DataObject {
 
 private int data1 = 100;
 private String data2 = "hello";
 private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
   {
  add("String 1");
  add("String 2");
  add("String 3");
   }
 };